# Asterisk as file converter

Tags: file, audio, format, converters, asterisk

It's posible to use asterisk binary as file format (wav -> g729) converter without running instance, **and how**.

My idea it's don't use productions servers to convert files.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can run asterisk core without channel modules, load only converter+socket interface. After that you can convert using that deamon.

You also can patch asterisk(it is opensource, yes) and get command-line option for convert.